# for x = str(y) in range(0,5) .... in python?

Tags: python

Real simple question. I'm trying to do this in python:

```
for x = str(y) in range(0,5):
```

so that y will hold an integer, and x will hold the string representation of said integer. I realize I could 2 line it pretty easily - just wanting a shortcut.

Also, I'm curious as to what exactly I'm asking. I'm sure this has been answered a bazillion times throughout the forum, but I have no idea what the heck to search for to find it.

Comment: Do you want to be able to refer to both `x` and `y` in your loop body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
for x in (str(y) for y in range(0, 5)):
```

This doesn't come with the overhead of instantiating the `str` list (though with 5 elements it's hardly an issue). Whenever I encounter this, though, I generally just use `str(y)` within the body of the loop.

Comment: No, that doesn't bind `y` in the loop body.

Comment: Though, that said, if you really want to avoid generating the list, then you should use `xrange`.

Answer (score 4):

An easy way is to use the `map()` function:

```
for y in map(str, range(0, 5)):
    # ...
```

The `map()` function takes an iterable and passes each elem through the first arg which is a callable.

Comment: Ah, I like this much better!

Comment: But that doesn't give you access to the `int`.

Comment: Hadn't realized that was a requirement, but yeah you are right it does not.

Comment: Could you wrap the `map` call in `enumerate` to also access the integer value?  For example: `for y,x in enumerate(map(str,range(0,5))):`, where `y` is the integer value and `x` is the string value

Comment: @Valdogg21: sure, but that only works if the range starts from 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension for achieving this:

```
str_list = ['%s'%(x) for x in range(0, 5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to search for [List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) most likely.

```
[(str(y),y) for y in range(0,5)]
```

This will give you tuples of strings and ints as a list, then iterate through that list like you would any other

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, since it relies upon a piece of code that doesn't actually compile.

```
for x,y in ((str(z), z) for z in range(0, 5)):
  print x, y
```

The above construct will bind `x` and `y` to a `str` and an `int`, respectively, for each loop iteration. The output is:

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
```

Comment: Actually, if you read directly under the piece of code that won't compile, I describe in English what I'm trying to accomplish with said code.  If my code compiled I wouldn't have the question.

also, it's kind of unhelpful how you didn't mention how I could have made it clearer. I specifically said in my post that I don't know what I'm asking :/